# MATLAB minimization

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the following minimization problem:

```
Ua=Pa+(a-c)*(a-c)'

Ub=Pb+(b-c)*(b-c)'

U=max(Ua,Ub)

c=arg min (det(U))
```

where `Pa`, `Pb` are known n*n matrices, `a` and `b` are known `n*1` vectors. the vector `c` is unknown and must be determined by minimizing determinant of `U`, which is the maximum of `Ua` and `Ub`.

Please let me know how I can solve this minimization problem in MATLAB?

Comment: Use `cvx`: http://cvxr.com/cvx/

Comment: @rayryeng I don't think cvx will work because this problem doesn't look convex? Just to start, the determinant is not at all convex.

Comment: @MatthewGunn I missed the determinant there. You're right. It won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
f= @(c)det(max(Pa+(a-c)*(a-c)',Pb+(b-c)*(b-c)'));
c= fminsearch(f,zeros(n,1));
```

(`zeros(n,1)` is the initial point)